# How to nest text and element in ember's emblem?

Tags: ember.js, emblem.js

In haml the following would produce the correctly nested HTML:

```
%p Hi There I'm inside this paragraph
  %button I'm also inside this paragraph
```

Produces:

```
<p> Hi There I'm inside this paragraph <button>I'm also inside this paragrpah</button></p>
```

In Emblem.js if I do:

```
p Hi There I'm inside this paragraph
  %button I'm also trying to be in the paragraph
```

It produces this:

```
<p> Hi There I'm inside this paragraph %button I'm also trying to be in the paragraph</p>
```

Does anyone know how to nest content and elements inside emblem.js?

Answer (score 0):

```css
p Hi There I'm inside this paragraph
  button I'm also trying to be in the paragraph
```

without the `%` will do the trick

I can recommend checking out http://emblemjs.com/syntax/ , it's a great resource that briefly explains every possible use case.